# ¿Qué diferencias hay realmente entre vh/vw y %?

Tags: css

Aplicando `CSS` a un sitio, me surgió la duda en `CSS` al momento de querer definir un tamaño variable de un contenedor `HTML`.

¿Cuál es el uso apropiado para usar **vh/vw** o porcentaje **%**, en que casos conviene utilizar una y en cuales otros la otra ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

### `vh` (Viewport Height)

Medición basada en la altura de la pantalla. Por ejemplo si damos una altura a un elemento de `height: 100vh;`, este elemento tendrá la misma altura que la pantalla.

### `vw` (Viewport Width)

Medición basada en lo ancho de la pantalla. Por ejemplo si damos un ancho a un elemento de `width: 100vw;`, este elemento tendrá lo mismo ancho que lo ancho que la pantalla.

### `%` (Porcentaje)

Medición basado en porcentaje. La medición en porcentaje será definida en relación a su elemento padre, a menos que éste se acompañe de una posición fija (`position:fixed;`) o absoluta (`position:absolute;`), que entonces en este caso su comportamiento ahora también respetará el tamaño de la pantalla.

## Considere el siguiente ejemplo:

```js
var docH = Math.max(document.documentElement.clientHeight, window.innerHeight || 0);
var viewportH = document.querySelector('.vh-height').offsetHeight;
var percentH = document.querySelector('.percent-height').offsetHeight;

var dhOut = document.getElementById('doc-height');
var vhOut = document.getElementById('vh-height');
var pctOut = document.getElementById('percent-height');

dhOut.innerHTML = docH;
vhOut.innerHTML = viewportH;
pctOut.innerHTML = percentH;
```

```css
body {
    background-color: #cbcbcb;
}
#parent{
    height:130px;
    width:400px;
    overflow: auto;
    background-color: #eee;
}
.child{
    width: 50%; /* 50% de ancho del elemento parent */
    color: #fff;
}
.vh-height{
    float:left;
    height:100vh; /* 100% de altura de viewPort */
    background-color:royalblue;
}
.percent-height{
    float:right;
    height:100%; /* 100% de altura pero relativamente a su elemento padre */
    background-color:brown;
}
```

```html
uno
<div id="parent">
    <div class="child vh-height">dos</div>
    <div class="child percent-height">tres</div>
</div>

(uno)  Altura del Documento/Viewport: <span id="doc-height"></span><br/>
(dos)  Altura del Viewport: <span id="vh-height"></span><br/>
(tres) Altura en Porcentaje (igual > altura del parent): <span id="percent-height"></span><br/>
```

También puedes ver este ejemplo en [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/shuffledPixels/74mt2ucc/)

Comment: Sería bueno añadir la razón del por qué del voto negativo

Comment: Muy buena explicación ¿Que pasa con vh/vw cuando se redimenciona la ventana?

Comment: Gracias amigo. Sus valores aumentan o disminuyen. Accede a esta nueva edición del enlace [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/shuffledPixels/74mt2ucc/1/) y redimensione la altura de la janala del Resultado.

Comment: Buena respuesta pero una aclaración: cuando el elemento tiene `position:absolute` y un ancho en porcentajes no es relativo a la pantalla sino a su ancestro posicionado más cercano a no ser que no haya ninguno.

Comment: Verdad @blonfu si algún elemento anterior tiene un `position:relative;`, ya no será relativo a la pantalla pero sí a ese elemento envoltorio, y su posicionamiento `top/left/etc` también. Pero si ninguno de los envolturos tiene ese estilo, será relativo a la pantalla.

Comment: Donde dice "altura de la pantalla" debería decir "altura del viewport".

Answer (score 3):

Es totalmente distinto usar viewports (vw/vh) que porcentajes (%)

[image: Viewports vs Porcentajes]
*Ejemplo con misma cantidad con las dos unidades: 60vw vs 60%*

**vw/vh:**
Esta unidad depende del tamaño del viewport, que es la ventana de visualización de donde se ve la página.

*Ejemplo:* Si mi navegador lo tengo abierto con un tamaño de 800px de ancho, 100vw serían 800px.

**Porcentaje %:**
Esta unidad es el porcentaje de tamaño del contenedor padre o relativo a este.

*Ejemplo:* Tengo un  de 1000px de ancho que contiene a  adentro con width: 20%, este medirá 200px.

Te dejo un codepen para que veas la diferencia jugando con el tamaño de la pantalla: https://codepen.io/bitxelus/pen/MvJGpZ

Answer (score 3):

**vw** y **wh** h son medidas relativas de acuerdo a la pantalla,

**vw** (viewport width): define el tañamano dependiendo de el ancho de la pantalla

**wh** (viewport high): define el tamaño dependiendo el largo de la pantalla

1vw o 1vh representan el 1 porciento de la altura o de la anchura respectivamente.

El **%** es la medida relativa de acuerdo a el contenedor, si el div padre tiene un tamaño de 500px y le colocas un width de 100% a un contenedor hijo este medirá 500px, si le colocas 50% este medirá 250px.