# ¿Cómo evitar desbordamiento de las cajas sobre el footer?

Tags: html, css

Estoy haciendo un pequeño ejercicio con `html`, `css` y `flexbox`, pero al momento de agregar mas elementos a un contenedor, este se desborda y mi propósito es que crezca dinamicamente. Anexo mi código

```css
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}

html {
    height: 100%;
}

body {
    min-height: 100vh !important;
}

.main {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    background: blue;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.main .header {
    width: 100%;
    height: 60px;
    background-color: #dbdada;
}

.main .container {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

.main .container .nav {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100%;
    background: purple;
}

.main .container .main-container {
    width: calc( 100% - 100px);
    height: 100%;
    background: yellow;
}

.main .container .main-container div {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: green;
}

.main .footer {
    align-self: flex-end;
    width: 100%;
    height: 60px;
    background: #dbdada;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/normalize.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">
</head>

<body>
    <div class="main">
        <div class="header">
            HEADER
        </div>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="nav">
                NAV
            </div>
            <div class="main-container">
                <div></div>
                <div></div>
                <div></div>
                <div></div>
                <div></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="footer">
            FOOTER
        </div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

En teoría, mi `nav` y `main-container` deben adaptarse y no desbordar el `container` padre que los envuelve

[image: Framework]

Lo que busco es que cada uno de los des div sean de la altura 100% del contenedor padre y vaya creciendo sin desbordar el footer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> En mi ejemplo usé etiquetas alternas a la constante de divs con ids que identifiquen a cada sección, pero la idea debería según la estructura propuesta aplicable y portable.

Comentarios:

- Partiendo de que ya trabajas con *Flexbox* podemos indicar que:

  - El contenedor del `nav` y el contenedor de los 3 `article` sean elementos flexibles
  - Lo anterior nos dará el beneficio de que ambos elementos contenedores se colocará horizontalmente uno a lado del otro
  - Una vez que tenemos eso cubierto podemos indicar que el `nav` tenga un 25% de ancho del espacio disponible
  - Consideremos dejar fuera de main los elementos que se estarían repitiendo como son el encabezado y el pie de página; [aquí puedes leer mas](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTML/Elemento/main)
- Como los 3 etiquetas `article` y son [elementos en bloque](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTML/Block-level_elements) ya tendríamos cubierto el punto de que queden uno sobre el otro, pero para que el ancho del `nav` no se pierda entonces le establecemos uno específico
- No veo necesario que les de un alto definido a los 3 `article` ya que estos aumentarán este valor a medida que tengan contenido
- Como tanto la etiqueta `header` como `footer` son elementos en bloque y los dejamos por fuera del alcance de la declaración de flexbox entonces abarcarán al ancho máximo disponible sin necesidad de que tu se los declares o debas maquetarlos de algún modo en específico mas complejo
- El papel de las clases declaradas nos ayuda a simplificar elegir a los elementos y aplicarles estilos (*la forma en que lo hago que no es la mejor ni la peor es una mera y pobre aproximación*), recomiendo leas mucho sobre [BEM CSS](https://en.bem.info/methodology/css/)
- Entonces son estas observaciones podrías evitar el uso de:

  - Declaración de altos (incluso aplicando `!important`)
  - Salvo algún punto que no estés mencionando en la pregunta, el uso de `wrap` no sería estrictamente necesario de aplicar, pero esto depende

Propuesta:

```html
    <style>
      * {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        text-align: center;
      }
      .contenedor {
        display: flex;
      }
      .contenedor-menu {
        background-color: yellow;
        width: 25%;
      }
      .contenedor-elementos {
        background-color: tomato;
        width: 75%;
      }
      .contenedor-encabezado, 
      .info-extra {
        background-color: #dbdada;
      }
      .contenedor-elementos__articulo {
        border: 1px solid;
      }
    </style>
    <header class="contenedor-encabezado">
      Header
    </header>
    <main class="contenedor">
      <nav class="contenedor-menu">
          Menú
      </nav>
      <section class="contenedor-elementos">
      
        <article class="contenedor-elementos__articulo">
          <p class="titulo">
            Div 1
          </p>
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Impedit nemo, aliquid reprehenderit quod, distinctio animi fugit saepe illo culpa ipsa non aut eum officiis maiores odio tempore, commodi sapiente quibusdam.
        </article>
        <article class="contenedor-elementos__articulo">
          <p class="titulo">
            Div 2
          </p>
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Cumque nihil at et, quia omnis dolores! Pariatur earum quis veritatis accusantium dolores minus, fugiat hic voluptates impedit tempora quia maiores temporibus!
        </article>
        <article class="contenedor-elementos__articulo">
          <p class="titulo">
            Div 3
          </p>
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Recusandae enim nemo ullam laborum, eligendi voluptate eveniet porro libero. Reprehenderit provident illo dignissimos culpa, quasi facere at libero quaerat, quod nostrum!
        </article>
      </section>
    </main>
    <footer class="info-extra">
      Footer
    </footer>
```

Ahora bajo esta misma idea podemos:

- Darle un alto mínimo a cada uno de los `article` de 33.3 [vh (*que recomiendo leas mas a detalle aqui en el aporte de @chun*)](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/93259/qu%C3%A9-diferencias-hay-realmente-entre-vh-vw-y), con eso lograremos que la altura mínima sea con respecto de la [ventana gráfica](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Learn/CSS/Building_blocks/Valores_y_unidades_CSS) y a medida que esta medida por el contenido deba crecer entonces haga que el contenedor tenga mayor altura.
- Le indicamos un `min-height` para que el contenido no se desborde de su contenedor

Quedando así:

```html
    <style>
          * {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            text-align: center;
          }
          .contenedor {
            display: flex;
          }
          .contenedor-menu {
            background-color: yellow;
            width: 25%;
          }
          .contenedor-elementos {
            background-color: tomato;
            width: 75%;
          }
          .contenedor-encabezado, 
          .info-extra {
            background-color: #dbdada;
          }
          .contenedor-elementos__articulo {
            border: 1px solid;
            min-height: 33.3vh;
          }
        </style>
        <header class="contenedor-encabezado">
          Header
        </header>
        <main class="contenedor">
          <nav class="contenedor-menu">
              Menú
          </nav>
          <section class="contenedor-elementos">
          
            <article class="contenedor-elementos__articulo">
              <p class="titulo">
                Div 1
              </p>
              Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Beatae, deserunt, laborum! Ratione dolorum maiores perferendis quidem repellat, accusantium provident recusandae incidunt. Illum numquam aspernatur deserunt quis, doloribus alias sequi! Magni.
              Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Laboriosam obcaecati quos suscipit possimus voluptatum illo, commodi, facilis ad. Assumenda ab dicta laboriosam, modi reprehenderit quae exercitationem nulla illo sapiente eveniet!
              Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Accusantium rem tempora a doloremque possimus maxime culpa sapiente iusto nihil suscipit itaque assumenda velit, voluptates. Commodi aut qui repudiandae reprehenderit, accusantium.
              Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Neque repellat est rerum dolorem, harum, impedit obcaecati porro exercitationem perferendis, incidunt provident iste officia eius non perspiciatis. Omnis magnam veritatis perspiciatis.
              Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptatum, temporibus doloribus molestiae labore commodi autem, corporis harum expedita quis tempore beatae delectus, dolorum, reiciendis unde repellat. Molestiae ipsum esse, minus.
            </article>
            <article class="contenedor-elementos__articulo">
              <p class="titulo">
                Div 2
              </p>
              Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Eaque voluptatibus laudantium, sapiente et nostrum accusantium suscipit ipsum veniam accusamus temporibus fuga natus provident nesciunt fugit deleniti ullam corporis autem eius!
              Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Nulla nobis aperiam sunt deserunt, provident illo suscipit eius qui, quisquam hic atque ullam facilis sint, eos aut nisi dolores ut voluptatum.
              Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Aut quae nam quisquam animi incidunt maxime molestias. Dicta voluptas repudiandae aperiam cum voluptate aliquid nihil dolor aspernatur quam! Dicta, quaerat, minima.
              Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Repudiandae ipsa odit quibusdam aut minus iste velit ex accusamus iusto nemo, sequi at repellat provident nihil labore aspernatur facere neque accusantium.
              Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Odit suscipit, pariatur ducimus quibusdam cumque, id quam error ad nesciunt, quia quo. Ea eligendi, provident, magni iure ullam laborum earum necessitatibus.
            </article>
            <article class="contenedor-elementos__articulo">
              <p class="titulo">
                Div 3
              </p>
              Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ipsum quaerat magnam velit quis nobis dolore expedita rem voluptates nulla doloribus accusantium libero error sunt fugiat vero consequatur, cum placeat vel?
              Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Rem, laborum quo repellendus quis nulla aperiam inventore beatae omnis deserunt pariatur. Corporis rerum asperiores necessitatibus ab excepturi dolore dolorum, accusamus delectus.
              Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Praesentium dolor voluptates aspernatur, vero harum fugiat enim soluta qui unde iusto labore rem dicta sapiente illum neque vel totam tempora quas!
              Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Dolore optio sint, porro dignissimos, ducimus corporis, quaerat sit harum natus quasi provident hic suscipit maxime dicta! Nobis amet quasi facilis iusto.
              Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ex ad, maxime accusantium earum reiciendis mollitia, quod saepe nostrum excepturi modi. Praesentium dolores exercitationem, pariatur cupiditate facilis asperiores impedit, nulla veniam?
              Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Expedita repellendus sed, explicabo iste assumenda reiciendis minima molestiae consequuntur, quasi dolorum suscipit molestias facilis culpa labore, provident excepturi eos corrupti velit.
            </article>
          </section>
        </main>
        <footer class="info-extra">
          Footer
        </footer>
```

Comment: Me he estado actualizando, no había utilizado flexbox y por lo general trabajaba con porcentajes y cabe decir que la propiedad `vh` y `vw` y claro que funcionaban, pero creo que era un problema más de resistirme a los nuevos conceptos.

Comment: Entonces, lo que me habías comentado anteriormente de el `height` en el `html, body` puede excluirse?

Comment: por ultimo, utilizo un `display:flex` para crear un **sticky footer** afecta en algo tenerlo en el `body`, ya que los elementos quedan por fuera del main, ademas que en el `footer` utilizo  `align-self: flex-end`?

Comment: hice una combinación de todo y creo que encontré la solución https://codepen.io/ferny-cortez/pen/bGpevaZ, una de las claves como mencionabas esta en la propiedad `min-height` y el manejo de `vh`

Answer (score 1):

Esto sucede debido a que cuando creas un **Contenedor flexible** utilizando la propiedad

```
.container {
  display: flex; /* or inline-flex */
}
```

Esto habilita solamente el contexto de "Flexible" a sus hijos directos.

Una solución para tu problema seria agregar esta propiedad de "Flex" a tu segundo contenedor de la siguiente forma:

```css
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}

body {
    display: flex;
    min-height: 100vh;
    flex-direction: column;
    background: blue;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.container {
    display: flex;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}

.container .nav {
    width: 100px;
    background: purple;
}

.main-container {
    width: 100%;
}

.main-container div {
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 600px; /* Puedes definir una altura minima para tus contenedores */
    background: green;
}

footer {
    align-self: flex-end;
    width: 100%;
    height: 60px;
    background: #dbdada;
}

header {
    width: 100%;
    height: 60px;
    background-color: #dbdada;
}
```

```html
<header>HEADER</header>
<div class="container">
    <div class="nav">
        NAV
    </div>
    <div class="main-container">
        <div>Div 1</div>
        <div>Div 2</div>
        <div>Div 3</div>
        <div>Div 4</div>
        <div>Div 5</div>
    </div>
</div>
<footer>FOOTER</footer>
```

Puedes revisar el código completo [Aquí](https://codepen.io/jerod8a/pen/PoNNeGw):

Saludos.

Comment: Sería usar el mismo display en los dos contenedores?

Comment: Lo intente y no me funcionó

Comment: Hola Ferny, veo que tienes varios clases a las que le estas agregando la propiedad height: 100%;, te recomendaría quitársela, nos podrías compartir el orden en el que buscas que tus elementos se desplieguen?, podría ser un dibujo si gustas. Te agrego una liga a mi respuesta para que veas el código completo.

Comment: Claro, al body le agrege el hight porque sin el mis elementos no tomaban ninguna altura

Comment: Tuviste oportunidad de revisar la liga? https://codepen.io/jerod8a/pen/PoNNeGw

Comment: no lo habia visto, aparte del display flex, se utiliza el flex-direction:column

Comment: Hay forma de que los div tengan el height: 100% de la altura de su contenedor padre? y aun asi no desbordar el footer?

Comment: Si existen varios caminos para lograr eso, pero depende de que es lo que busques, Buscas el footer se recorra al final del contenido? o buscas que siempre este presente en pantalla? si lo que buscas es lo segundo, agregando un overflow-x: auto; al elemento .main-container bastaría.

Comment: busco que se recorra al final del contenido, no importa si no esta visible en pantalla, para mi necesidad es mas importante donde se muestran los div

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/111838/discussion-between-jesus-ochoa-and-ferny-cortez).

Answer (score 1):

Ehhh!!! ya casi lo tienes.

Ejecuta el siguiente código y veras que es el resultado deseado:

```css
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}

html {
    height: 100%;
}

body {
    min-height: 100vh !important;
}

.main {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    background: blue;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.main .header {
    width: 100%;
    height: 60px;
    background-color: #dbdada;
}

.main .container {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

.main .container .nav {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100%;
    background: purple;
}

.main .container .main-container {
    width: calc( 100% - 100px);
    height: 100%;
    background: yellow;
}

.main .container .main-container div {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: green;
}

.main .footer {
    align-self: flex-end;
    position:fixed;
    
    width: 100%;
    height: 60px;
    background: #dbdada;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/normalize.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">
</head>

<body>
    <div class="main">
        <div class="header">
            HEADER
        </div>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="nav">
                NAV
            </div>
            <div class="main-container">
                <div></div>
                <div></div>
                <div></div>
                <div></div>
                <div></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="footer">
            FOOTER
        </div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Y todo es el mismo código que colgaste en tu pregunta, ¿pero que hice? ¿magia..?

Pues la magia no existe , asi que solo agregue: `position:fixed;` para tu `.main .footer`. y listo tienes el resultado. Si deseas el mismo efecto el header, también puedes agregarlo.

Lo que hace position fixed es mantener un elemento posicionado fijamente.

Answer (score 1):

> Para solucionar el problema me base en la respuesta de [@BetaM](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/128299/betam) y agregando algunas cosas que ya tenia anteriormente.

**Sticky Footer**

- Para el ***sticky footer*** utilice en el body lo siguiente:

  ```
  body {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 100vh;
  }
  ```

***`display: flex:`*** Ayuda a alinear los elementos dentro de el layout y distribuir su espacio. [Ver Aquí](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Conceptos_Basicos_de_Flexbox)

***`flex-wrap:wrap:*** Proporciona un salto de linea si los elementos no caben en la linea que se esta trabajando. [Ver Aquí](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Conceptos_Basicos_de_Flexbox#Contenedores_flex_Multi-l%C3%ADnea_con_flex-wrap)

***`width:100%:`*** Se aseguro que el ancho del `body` ocupe el 100% de nuestro dispositivo.

***`min-height:100vh:`*** El tamaño mínimo del `body` sera el ancho del dispositivo, esto da la pauta para que aumenta por encima de ese valor inicial.

```
   footer{
    align-self:flex-end
    width:100%;
    height:50px;
   }
```

***`align-self:flex-end`:*** Al ser el `body` el contenedor padre del `footer`, este se ve afectado por el `display:flex` del contenedor que lo envuelve, y es por esto que la propiedad `align-self:flex-end` ubicara siempre nuestro footer al final del contenedor padre. [¿Cómo hacer un sticky footer con flexbox?](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZxuAc1Ye_VE&t=1517s)

***`width:100%`:*** Al estar trabajando con `flex-wrap:wrap` el largo del elemento `footer` al 100% se asegura que ocupe una linea para el solo, ocupando el 100% del largo del dispositivo.

***`height:50px:`*** Le da un ancho definido al `footer`

**Solución al problema de desbordamiento**

```
   main {
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    background: blanchedalmond;
    min-height: calc(100vh - 50px);
  }
```

- A la etiqueta `main` se le da la propiedad `display:flex` para poder manipular el flujo de los elementos a los que envuelve, así como la propiedad `min-height:calc(100vh - 50px)`, la propiedad anterior es con la finalidad de respetar el ancho del footer y mostrar todos los elementos en caso dado de que el contenido no sobrepase esos valores, si llega a sobrepasarlos solamente crecerá sin desbordamiento.

  ```
     main nav {
      width: 25%;
      background: crimson;
     }

    main .articles {
     width: 90%;
     background: darkslategrey;
    }
  ```
- Los contenedores `main` y `articles` son de tipo bloque por lo que ocuparan el 100% del ancho del contenedor padre, lo importante en este punto es dividir el contenedor que los envuelve, al `nav` se le asigna un largo del 25% y su resto 75% a la caja `.articles`, de esta forma obtenemos el 100% del largo del dispositivo y sin generar salto de linea.

  ```
     article {
       min-height: 100vh;
     }
  ```
- A los elementos `article` no le definimos su largo, ya que al ser elementos de tipo bloque ocupan el 100% del contenedor que lo envuelve, se le asigna un `min-height: 100vh`, la medida aquí puede ser  discrecional, es decir al tamaño que deseemos, en este caso sera del tamaño de la pantalla del dispositivo.

> Al querer hacer la altura dinámica de los elementos es importante no
> definirla tal cual, sino apoyarnos de la propiedad `css`
> **`min-height:`**, ya que sera el valor mínimo de su altura y permitirá que el contenedor o elemento crezca hasta tener un tamaño
> indefinido. Lo anterior da como resultado una altura dinámica.

[Solución Completa Aquí](https://codepen.io/ferny-cortez/pen/bGpevaZ)

Answer (score 0):

Lo que pasa es que no usas el valor `align-content: stretch;`, y el main principal seria una columna, tu `html` queda igual

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**CSS**

```
        body{
            margin: 0px;
        }
        .main{
            display: flex;
            flex-direction: column;
        }
        .main div{
            display: flex;
            width: 100%;
            min-height: 100px;
        }
        .header{
            background-color: #dbdada;
            justify-content: center;
            align-items: center;
        }
        .nav {
            flex: 30%;
            max-width: 30%;
            display: flex;
            justify-content: center;
            align-items: center;
            background-color: yellow;
        }
        .main-container{
            flex: 70%;
            max-width: 70%;
            display: flex;
            flex-direction: column;
            align-items: stretch;
            align-content: stretch;
        }
        .main-container div{
            border-top: 1px solid blue;
            height: 300px;
            display: flex;
            align-items: center;
            justify-content: center;
        }
        .footer{
            background-color: #000000;
            color: #ffffff;
            justify-content: center;
            align-items: center;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Yo te aconsejo que siempre que uses flexbox, uses los prefijos para la compatibilidad con los navegadores mas antiguos, asi evitas problemas futuros. por otro lado yo lo haría asi, usando el mismo html y solo modificando un poco el css:

NO creo necesario que tus artículos tengan el mismo alto, a menos que todos tengan el mismo númeor de caracteres e imágenes, de otra forma romperían el diseño;

```css
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}
.main {
    min-height: 100vh;
    background: blue;
    display:-webkit-box; 
    display:-moz-box; 
    display:-webkit-flex; 
    display:-ms-flexbox; 
    display:flex;
    -moz-box-direction:column; 
    -webkit-box-direction:column; 
    -webkit-box-orient:vertical; 
    -webkit-flex-direction:column; 
    -ms-flexbox-direction:column; 
    -ms-flex-direction:column; 
    flex-direction:column;
}

.main .header {
    height: 60px;
    background-color: #dbdada;
}

.main .container {
    display:-webkit-box; 
    display:-moz-box; 
    display:-webkit-flex; 
    display:-ms-flexbox; 
    display:flex;
    flex-grow: 1;
}

.main .container .nav {
    width: 100px;
    background: purple;
}

.main .container .main-container {
    width: calc( 100% - 100px);
    background: yellow;
    display:-webkit-box; 
    display:-moz-box; 
    display:-webkit-flex; 
    display:-ms-flexbox; 
    display:flex;
    -moz-box-direction:column; 
    -webkit-box-direction:column; 
    -webkit-box-orient:vertical; 
    -webkit-flex-direction:column; 
    -ms-flexbox-direction:column; 
    -ms-flex-direction:column; 
    flex-direction:column;
}

.main .container .main-container div {
    width: 100%; 
    background: green;
    padding: 20px;
    flex-grow: 1;
}

.main .footer {
    height: 60px;
    background: #dbdada;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
        <div class="header">
            HEADER
        </div>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="nav">
                NAV
            </div>
            <div class="main-container">
                <div>
                What is Lorem Ipsum?

                Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
                Why do we use it?

              </div>
              <div>
              What is Lorem Ipsum?

              Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
              Why do we use it?

                </div>
                <div>
What is Lorem Ipsum?

Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
Why do we use it?

                </div>
                <div>
What is Lorem Ipsum?

Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
Why do we use it?

                </div>
                <div>
What is Lorem Ipsum?

Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
Why do we use it?

              </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="footer">
            FOOTER
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: @BetaM, yo pensaba igual, pero no tienes idea de los clientes a los que les he trabajado, que en sus empresas; soporte no les actualiza sus softwares, y no tienen permitido actualizarlos, pienso que deberían dejar de existir esos navegadores, pero la realizadad me ha enseñado a ser prudente a la hora de entregar una maquetación, asi que prefiero trabajar una sola vez y completo, que dos veces y con reclamos, muchos editores tienen ya plugs para agregar automáticamente los prefijos a tu proyecto.