# ¿Cómo "sacar" el espacio en blanco del final de la página?

Tags: html, css

Mi pregunta es ¿Cómo hago para eliminar ese espacio en blanco que se muestra en la página? Debajo dejo el código HTML para mayor información. Cualquier ayuda será agradecida.
Muestro la imagen y debajo el código para una mayor información del código utilizado.
Lo que deseo hacer es eliminar ese espacio en blanco, para que el form del login me quede centrado en la pantalla.
Desde ya, muchas gracias!

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport"
    content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css"
    integrity="sha384-JcKb8q3iqJ61gNV9KGb8thSsNjpSL0n8PARn9HuZOnIxN0hoP+VmmDGMN5t9UJ0Z" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js"
    integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous">
</script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.1/dist/umd/popper.min.js"
integrity="sha384-9/reFTGAW83EW2RDu2S0VKaIzap3H66lZH81PoYlFhbGU+6BZp6G7niu735Sk7lN" crossorigin="anonymous">
</script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"
integrity="sha384-B4gt1jrGC7Jh4AgTPSdUtOBvfO8shuf57BaghqFfPlYxofvL8/KUEfYiJOMMV+rV" crossorigin="anonymous">
</script>
</head>
<header>
  <app-navbar></app-navbar>
</header>
<div *ngIf="isLogged; else loggedOut">
</div>
<ng-template #loggedOut>
<body>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row justify-content-center">
        <div class="col-md-4">
          <form class="form-register shadow p-4 mb-4" #f="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="onLogin()" novalidate>
            <h3 class="titulo text-center">Iniciar Sesión</h3>
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="nombreUsuarioComplejo">Nombre de Usuario:</label>
              <input type="text" name="nombreUsuarioComplejo" id="nombreUsuarioComplejo" class="form-control"
                [(ngModel)]="nombreUsuarioComplejo" required>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="contra">Contraseña:</label>
              <input type="password" name="contra" id="contra" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="contra" required>
              <!-- <button id="show_password" class="btn btn-primary" type="button" onclick="mostrarPassword()"> <span class="fa fa-eye-slash icon"></span> </button> -->
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <p class="text-center">Si su usuario no fue generado, contáctese con <a
                  href="mailto:easyfutbolinformation@gmail.com">EasyFutbol</a></p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-12 text-center ">
              <button class=" btn btn-block btn-success" style="border-radius:50px;" [disabled]="!f.valid"><i
                  class="fas fa-sign-in-alt"></i> Iniciar Sesión</button>
            </div>
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!-- <div *ngIf="f.submitted && isLoginFail" class="alert alert-danger mt-3">El usuario y/o la contraseña son incorrectos.</div> -->
    </div>
  </body>
</ng-template>
</html>
```

Comment: puedes agregar tu código?

Comment: Disculpá, estoy viendo como añadir el código. Soy nuevo en esto!

Comment: Agregado el código..

Comment: Procura evitar las mayúsculas sostenidas, por favor. Suele asimilarse a que gritas y pues veo que en tu caso no es la idea.

Comment: Bien, pido disculpas si se mal interpretó.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AL `div` con la clase `container` le puedes hacer los siguientes cambios:

Escribe una regla CSS específica:

- Dale un alto de `100vh`
- A dicho contenedor dale un  `display flex`
- Para desplazar el centro el formulario puedes hacer esto:

  - Verticalmente con `justify-content`
  - Horizontalmnete con `align-items`

Quedando de esta forma:

```
  .container {
    height: 100vh;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
  }
```

**Fuentes de consulta**

- [unidad de medida `vh`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Learn/CSS/Building_blocks/Valores_y_unidades_CSS)
- [Módulo Flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Conceptos_Basicos_de_Flexbox)
- [Publicación en la comunidad sobre unidades de medida (*créditos a @Chun*)](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/93259/qu%C3%A9-diferencias-hay-realmente-entre-vh-vw-y)

Comment: He podido resolverlo con esa ayuda. Muchas gracias!